# why MTU change from 1500 to 9000

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, network-interface, dmesg

in `/var/log/message` file we found something interesting

```
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: changing MTU from 1500 to 9000
```

we can see the interface card - en3j87
change from 1500 MTU to 9000

is it normal ?

```
Mar  9 07:07:33 linux54 dbus-daemon: dbus[1153]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
Mar  9 07:08:30 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1: registered PHC device on en3j87
Mar  9 07:08:30 linux54 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): en3j87: link is not ready
Mar  9 07:08:31 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: detected SFP+: 5
Mar  9 07:08:31 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
Mar  9 07:08:31 linux54 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): en3j87: link becomes ready
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1: removed PHC on en3j87
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: changing MTU from 1500 to 9000
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1: registered PHC device on en3j87
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): en3j87: link is not ready
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: team0: Port device en3j87 added
Mar  9 07:08:32 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: detected SFP+: 5
Mar  9 07:08:33 linux54 kernel: ixgbe 0000:0b:00.1 en3j87: NIC Link is Up 10 Gbps, Flow Control: RX/TX
Mar  9 07:08:33 linux54 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): en3j87: link becomes ready
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that your interface has been configured to use jumbo frames. If the connection is working, then it’s nothing to worry about, and you’ll get higher throughput as a result. (If it works, it means the network equipment the interface is connected to has also been configured for jumbo frames.)

Interfaces start with a traditional 1500-byte MTU and are reconfigured to 9000 by the network setup if necessary (in RHEL, if the interface configuration specifies `MTU=9000`). The log message you see is perfectly normal.

Comment: The key point here is that it was configured, it does not change alone. Now if people changes randomly MTUs, that is another problem.

Comment: we not change it manual , all machines are configured to MTU=9000 , so I not understand why log explain to move from MTU=1500 to 9000

Comment: The `MTU=9000` configuration is the configuration which enables jumbo frames. Interfaces start with a traditional 1500-byte MTU and are reconfigured to 9000 by the network setup when it sees `MTU=9000`.

Comment: so you not see any problem about the mssg? ( from 1500 to 9000 ) ,, what I not understand why he start with 1500 , while interface configured to 9000? , as you lnow if all machines are configured to 9000 , then it is important that all them will be 9000 and no 1500 , it can cause network problem

Comment: from - https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/8563/typical-hdp-cluster-network-configuration-best-pra.html   ,   Look into defining MTU for all interfaces on the cluster to support Jumbo Frames (typically MTU=9000). But only do this make certain that all nodes and switches support this functionality. Inconsistent MTU or undefined MTU configurations can produce serious problems with the network.

Comment: so you can see that if some interface in some point of time is mtu=1500 then it can cause a Sirius problem

Comment: I want to add that we have hadoop cluster and all machines are with MTU=9000

Comment: The MTU isn’t configured before the link is up, so the drivers uses the (safe) default. But the MTU is switched to 9000 *during interface setup*, from your logs within a second. In any case, jumbo frames only have to be *supported* across the network, having a smaller MTU for less than a second during setup won’t have any impact.

Comment: Incidentally (and this is true for many of your questions), you’re paying for RHEL support, and presumably for Hortonworks support; why not ask your support contacts there?

Comment: because this is pure system issue , and you are give the right direction

Comment: @Kitt YOU ARE THE BEST

Answer (score 1):

That message is something specific of your network module (`ixgbe`) and totally normal(not a problem). If you take a look at the source code of that module, file [`ixgbe_main.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/ixgbe/ixgbe_main.c) line 6719, you will notice that the driver informs whenever there is a MTU change happening. Snippet of the code for context:

```
static int ixgbe_change_mtu(struct net_device *netdev, int new_mtu)
{
    struct ixgbe_adapter *adapter = netdev_priv(netdev);

    if (adapter->xdp_prog) {
        int new_frame_size = new_mtu + ETH_HLEN + ETH_FCS_LEN +
                     VLAN_HLEN;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < adapter->num_rx_queues; i++) {
            struct ixgbe_ring *ring = adapter->rx_ring[i];

            if (new_frame_size > ixgbe_rx_bufsz(ring)) {
                e_warn(probe, "Requested MTU size is not supported with XDP\n");
                return -EINVAL;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * For 82599EB we cannot allow legacy VFs to enable their receive
     * paths when MTU greater than 1500 is configured.  So display a
     * warning that legacy VFs will be disabled.
     */
    if ((adapter->flags & IXGBE_FLAG_SRIOV_ENABLED) &&
        (adapter->hw.mac.type == ixgbe_mac_82599EB) &&
        (new_mtu > ETH_DATA_LEN))
        e_warn(probe, "Setting MTU > 1500 will disable legacy VFs\n");

    e_info(probe, "changing MTU from %d to %d\n", netdev->mtu, new_mtu);

    /* must set new MTU before calling down or up */
    netdev->mtu = new_mtu;

    if (netif_running(netdev))
        ixgbe_reinit_locked(adapter);

    return 0;
}
```

Specific line where you are supposed to be notified that the MTU has changed:

```
e_info(probe, "changing MTU from %d to %d\n", netdev->mtu, new_mtu);
```